# Loop through range of hyperlinks and pull data

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am new to VBA and could really use your help on this.

- I have a folder that has 3 types of files (APL, PL, BPL) and a master file. I would like to pull specific data from specific sheets in each of these files and pull it back into the master file.
- The issue I am having is there are over 50 files in this folder (1 APL to 19 APL, 20 PL to 40 PL, 41 BPL to 56 BPL).
- How do I create a loop that will pull specific cells and paste them back in a orderly fashion( 1 through 56 rows) in the master file starting cells C5, D5, E5 in the CONSOLIDATION tab.
- Each file in the folder should be labeled a number (1,2,3) followed by either APL, PL or BPL.
- Based on the file name the loop should pull specific cells.
- For any APL files - Copy summary tab Cells A1, A2 and A7 paste in master file Consolidation tab starting C5, D5, E5
- For any PL files - copy Data tab cells D4, D7 and G98
- For any BPL files - Liquidation tabl cells E4,R5,T6
- Below is what my CONSOLIDATION sheet looks like

## Pool    Data    Date    Processor

1   APL
2   APL
3   APL
4   APL
5   APL
6   APL
7   APL
8   APL
9   APL
10  APL
11  APL
12  APL
13  APL
14  APL
15  APL
16  APL
17  APL
18  APL
19  APL
20  PL
21  PL
22  PL
23  PL
24  PL
25  PL
26  PL
27  PL
28  PL
29  PL
30  PL
31  PL
32  PL
33  PL
34  PL
35  PL
36  PL
37  PL
38  PL
39  PL
40  PL
41  BPL
42  BPL
43  BPL
44  BPL
45  BPL
46  BPL
47  BPL
48  BPL
49  BPL
50  BPL
51  BPL
52  BPL
53  BPL
54  BPL
55  BPL
56  BPL

Comment: You create a loop by saying something like `For r = 1 To 56` `'code goes here` `Next`, but it's not clear from your question exactly what code you want us to write for you, so you may have to do most of the work.

Comment: i am new to vba which is why i am hoping someone can teach me how to write somethign like this, the loop should essentially open each of the files in the folder and copy data and paste in the master file and then go to the next file in the folder

Comment: the master file consolidation tab has a list of 1 to 56 in column B and i want to paste data in cells starting c5,d5,e5. I just need the macro to know what cells to pull based on the name of the file if its APL copy summary tab Cells A1, A2 and A7, if its PL copy data tab cells D4, D7 and G98 BPL and if its BPL pull Liquidation tab cells E4,R5,T6

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to get you started.  Once you understand the copy/paste parts, you should be able to adapt to the rest of your data and the rest of your files.  This code needs to live in your master workbook and you must have the master workbook activated/selected when you start running the code.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim tempWb As Workbook
Dim masterWb As Workbook

Set masterWb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim Path As String

'change to your path
Path = "C:\TEMP\test\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")

Do While Len(Filename) > 0

    'make sure the file name contains 1 of the 3 strings
    If InStr(Filename, "APL") > 0 Or InStr(Filename, "PL") Or InStr(Filename, "BPL") Then

        'split the file name to get the number and file text
        splitByPeriod = Split(Filename, ".")
        splitBySpace = Split(splitByPeriod(0), " ")

        Dim fileNumber As Integer
        Dim fileText As String

        fileNumber = splitBySpace(0)
        fileText = splitBySpace(1)

        'activate the master
        masterWb.Activate
        Worksheets("Consolidation").Activate

        Dim rowNumber As Integer
        rowNumber = fileNumber + 4

        'open the file
        Set tempWb = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

        If fileText = "APL" Then

            'activate the workbook
            tempWb.Activate
            'activate the summary tab
            Worksheets("summary").Activate
            'copy the data in range A1
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.Copy

            'activate your summary workbook
            masterWb.Activate
            'activate the consolidation tab
            Worksheets("Consolidation").Activate

            'activate the cell to place the data in
            Range("C" & rowNumber).Select
            'paste the data
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'repeat as necessary
            'add additional copy/paste code here


        ElseIf fileText = "PL" Then

            'add copy/paste code

        ElseIf fileText = "BPL" Then

            'add copy/paste code

        End If

        'close the file, don't save, don't display alerts about not saving
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        tempWb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If

    Filename = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks David a couple questions for you 1) what does the split by period and split by space do ? 2) what does the the RowNumber = FileNumber + 4 do

Comment: well you could put in a break in the code and use the locals window to see what the variables contain...  but if the file name is '1 APL.xlsm' then fileNumber = 1 and fileText = "APL".  I think you should be able to figure out the second one.